# $|x+y|=|y+x|$ in a normed group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normed-spaces, noncommutative-algebra

> A normed group $(X,+,|\cdot|)$ is a set $X$ equipped with a group operation $+$ and a function $|\cdot|:X\to\Bbb R$ called a norm such that
>
> - $|x|=0\iff x=0$
> - $|x-y|\le|x|+|y|$.

From these properties one can also deduce $|x|\ge0$, $|{-x}|=|x|$, and $|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$. (I am using additive notation for the group because the norm's subadditivity property is more consistent with additive  notation than multiplicative, but we are not assuming that $+$ is commutative.) These axioms are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ to be a metric, and they can also be understood as the intersection of the axioms of an normed $R$-vector space (which adds the axiom $r\in R,x\in X\to|rx|=|r|_R|x|$ where $|\cdot|_R$ is the norm on $R$) and an absolute value over a ring (which adds $|xy|=|x||y|$), but I haven't found any literature directly on normed groups defined like this.

It follows from the definition that $d(x+z,y+z)=d(x,y)$  ($d$ is right translation invariant), but I haven't managed to show $d(z+x,z+y)=d(x,y)$, nor $d(-x,-y)=d(x,y)$ or that the topology induced by $d$ turns $X$ into a topological group, and I think the key is the "identity" $|x+y|=|y+x|$, which I have not managed to prove or disprove.

> **Claim** If $(X,+,|\cdot|)$ is a normed group, then $|x+y|=|y+x|$.

**Edit:** Turns out this is mentioned in the literature (by which I mean Wikipedia), under the terminology of a [length function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_function). Unfortunately I don't see any counterexamples of noncommutative normed groups there which don't satisfy $|x+y|=|y+x|$.

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia article tells you how to construct counterexamples: given any presentation of a group $G$ there's an induced length function given by the length of the shortest word in the generators that forms a given $g \in G$ (this is the origin of the term "length function"). There's no reason this should satisfy the condition you want, which is equivalent to length being invariant under conjugation. For example, take $G = F_2$ with the free presentation by two generators $x, y$ and no relations. Then $x$ and $yxy^{-1}$ are conjugate but do not have the same length. The induced metric is also not left translation invariant.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but... you say (1) the induced metric is not left translation invariant and (2) $xy$ and $yx$ having the same length for all $x$ and $y$ is equivalent to length being invariant under conjugation. Isn't (1) precisely what you would want to use to prove (2) though?

Comment: @Mike: no. The point is that $xy$ and $yx$ are conjugate, and all pairs of conjugate elements of a group can be written in this form. This is a purely group-theoretic fact that has nothing to do with metrics or lengths.

Comment: You just taught me something, thanks for the nice comment!

Comment: Oh, that was simpler than I thought it would be. I think I convinced myself that it transformed $abcd$ to $a^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}d^{-1}$ but that's not quite right. What about continuity?

Comment: I thought that the conjugation trick would give a failure of continuity, but in fact the word metric generates a topological group trivially, because the metric is discrete. Is there a way to vary the construction so that you have $|xy|\ne|yx|$ in a continuous metric?